Really long boot time
I have Compaq 610 dualbooting Windows XP and ubuntu.
When chosing win xp, it starts booting right up, but when chosing ubuntu, it's black screen for 5 min and then booting more 2 minutes with ubuntu logo. Why is there the black screen for so long. I'm new with linux.
The boot menu shoud be the default one,
then the black screen,  then boot with a logo
I have 64 bit intel T5870 cpu and meet all other requirements, I just want to get rid of the balck screen

which boot loader are you using? ... please add a picture of the screen to your post

What Ubuntu release are you using?  My Compaq 610 won't run any supported release of Ubuntu as its an unsupported architecture, and thus was retired from its prior Quality Assurance testing role.

Using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, when installing I didn't see any message about being not supported

The specs of Compaq 610 are too low to run Ubuntu 24.04 (see system requirements https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements). You can find some very lightweight operating systems here (especially, try the Raspberry Pi OS for PC and Mac, it should fly on your laptop).

This question is similar to: What options do I have to upgrade an unsupported i386 version of Ubuntu to an operating system with newer packages?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
